# How to enable concurrent build from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, concurrency, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

Are there any Jenkins properties to enable concurrent builds from within a pipeline? My pipeline disables concurrent builds for one node with `properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])` and I would like to re-enable it when run on a different node.

I have tried `properties([enableConcurrentBuilds()])` and `properties([concurrentBuild()])` but both are invalid options.

Answer (score 1):

While concurrent builds are enabled by default; during the pipeline execution it would be much more flexible having the ability to disable/enable concurrency.

e.g. if some specific stages may not allow concurrency but all remaining stages do.

Comment: what if this option(disableConcurrentBuilds()) is added by default part of shared library and need to be enable for one project. ? there is possibility, shared library is public or managed by different team which may not allow developer to modify default values in shared lib.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent builds are enabled by default but if you use disableConcurrentBuild in your pipeline then it will be disabled. You can just use empty properties block as:

```
properties([])
```

Then the concurrent builds will be re-enabled.

Comment: Good idea but doesn't work. The job continues not allowing concurrent builds.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent builds are enabled by default. That is why the is the `disableConcurrentBuilds()` function. So there is no need to add any additional code to your pipeline to enable concurrent builds.

Comment: what if this option(disableConcurrentBuilds()) is added by default part of shared library and need to be enable for one project. ? there is possibility, shared library is public or managed by different team which may not allow developer to modify default values in shared lib.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]

```java
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('sleep') {
            agent any
            options {
                throttle(['test_4'])
            }
            steps {
                sh "sleep 500"
                echo "Done"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not enabled by default. Is there no way to enable? I was also trying modify default workspace created by Pipeline that is also not working for multibranch pipeline.